# Unable to get Displayport output working with a Nvidia Optimus Laptop

Tags: nvidia, manjaro, display-settings, displayport, hybrid-graphics

I have a Dell [Latitude e6420](https://www.dell.com/us/dfb/p/latitude-e6420/pd) laptop with a discrete Nvidia NVS 4200m graphics card in addition to an [Intel HD 3000](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/products/81500/graphics-drivers/graphics-for-2nd-generation-intel-processors/intel-hd-graphics-3000.html).

When at home, I use a docking station which is connected to another monitor. I used to have my monitor connected to the docking station via DVI which worked perfectly fine. But as I recently got a new monitor ([Dell P2418D](https://www.dell.com/en-us/work/shop/dell-24-monitor-p2418d/apd/210-amuh/monitors-monitor-accessories)) with a resolution which is too high for DVI, I attempted to connect it to the docking station via Displayport.

When using the new monitor (connected to the docking station via Displayport) under Windows 10 (I have a Manjaro/Windows dual-boot system), it works fine. However, if I try to use it under Linux, it is recognized by `xrandr`, but the monitor doesn't recognize any input signal:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 2560 x 1440, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS-1 connected primary 1600x900+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 310mm x 174mm
   1600x900      60.06*+  59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82    40.32  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
VGA-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
LVDS-1-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA-1-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1-1 connected 2560x1440+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 526mm x 296mm
   2560x1440     59.95*+
   1920x1440     60.00  
   1856x1392     60.01  
   1792x1344     75.00    60.01  
   2048x1152     59.90    59.91  
   1920x1200     59.88    59.95  
   2048x1080     60.00    24.00  
   1920x1080     59.97    59.96    60.00    50.00    59.94    59.93    24.00    23.98  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1600x1200     75.00    70.00    65.00    60.00  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1400x1050     74.76    59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    60.00    50.00    59.94    59.74  
   1024x768      75.05    60.04    75.03    70.07    60.00  
   960x720       75.00    60.00  
   928x696       75.00    60.05  
   896x672       75.05    60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       75.00    70.00    65.00    60.00    72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x576i      50.00  
   700x525       74.76    59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x480i      60.00    59.94  
   640x512       75.02    60.02  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    75.00    72.81    75.00    60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   720x400       70.08  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       75.00  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       75.03    70.07    60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   416x312       74.66  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       72.19    75.12    60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       72.81    75.00    60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
DP-1-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
  1600x900 (0x45) 246.000MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width  1600 start 1728 end 1900 total 2200 skew    0 clock 111.82KHz
        v: height  900 start  901 end  904 total  932           clock  59.99Hz
  1600x900 (0x46) 186.500MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width  1600 start 1624 end 1640 total 1680 skew    0 clock 111.01KHz
        v: height  900 start  901 end  904 total  926           clock  59.94Hz
  1600x900 (0x47) 118.250MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1600 start 1696 end 1856 total 2112 skew    0 clock  55.99KHz
        v: height  900 start  903 end  908 total  934           clock  59.95Hz
  1600x900 (0x48) 97.500MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1600 start 1648 end 1680 total 1760 skew    0 clock  55.40KHz
        v: height  900 start  903 end  908 total  926           clock  59.82Hz
  1400x900 (0x4a) 103.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1400 start 1480 end 1624 total 1848 skew    0 clock  56.01KHz
        v: height  900 start  903 end  913 total  934           clock  59.96Hz
  1400x900 (0x4b) 86.500MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1400 start 1448 end 1480 total 1560 skew    0 clock  55.45KHz
        v: height  900 start  903 end  913 total  926           clock  59.88Hz
  1440x810 (0x4c) 198.125MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width  1440 start 1548 end 1704 total 1968 skew    0 clock 100.67KHz
        v: height  810 start  811 end  814 total  839           clock  60.00Hz
  1440x810 (0x4d) 151.875MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width  1440 start 1464 end 1480 total 1520 skew    0 clock  99.92KHz
        v: height  810 start  811 end  814 total  833           clock  59.97Hz
  1368x768 (0x4e) 85.250MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1368 start 1440 end 1576 total 1784 skew    0 clock  47.79KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  781 total  798           clock  59.88Hz
  1368x768 (0x4f) 72.250MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1368 start 1416 end 1448 total 1528 skew    0 clock  47.28KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  781 total  790           clock  59.85Hz
  1280x800 (0x50) 174.250MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width  1280 start 1380 end 1516 total 1752 skew    0 clock  99.46KHz
        v: height  800 start  801 end  804 total  829           clock  59.99Hz
  1280x800 (0x51) 134.250MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width  1280 start 1304 end 1320 total 1360 skew    0 clock  98.71KHz
        v: height  800 start  801 end  804 total  823           clock  59.97Hz
  1280x800 (0x52) 83.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1352 end 1480 total 1680 skew    0 clock  49.70KHz
        v: height  800 start  803 end  809 total  831           clock  59.81Hz
  1280x800 (0x53) 71.000MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1360 total 1440 skew    0 clock  49.31KHz
        v: height  800 start  803 end  809 total  823           clock  59.91Hz
  1280x720 (0x54) 156.125MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width  1280 start 1376 end 1512 total 1744 skew    0 clock  89.52KHz
        v: height  720 start  721 end  724 total  746           clock  60.00Hz
  1280x720 (0x55) 120.750MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width  1280 start 1304 end 1320 total 1360 skew    0 clock  88.79KHz
        v: height  720 start  721 end  724 total  740           clock  59.99Hz
  1280x720 (0x56) 74.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1344 end 1472 total 1664 skew    0 clock  44.77KHz
        v: height  720 start  723 end  728 total  748           clock  59.86Hz
  1280x720 (0x57) 63.750MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1360 total 1440 skew    0 clock  44.27KHz
        v: height  720 start  723 end  728 total  741           clock  59.74Hz
  1024x768 (0x58) 133.475MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width  1024 start 1100 end 1212 total 1400 skew    0 clock  95.34KHz
        v: height  768 start  768 end  770 total  794           clock  60.04Hz
  1024x768 (0x59) 65.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock  48.36KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock  60.00Hz
  960x720 (0x5a) 117.000MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   960 start 1024 end 1128 total 1300 skew    0 clock  90.00KHz
        v: height  720 start  720 end  722 total  750           clock  60.00Hz
  928x696 (0x5b) 109.150MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   928 start  976 end 1088 total 1264 skew    0 clock  86.35KHz
        v: height  696 start  696 end  698 total  719           clock  60.05Hz
  896x672 (0x5c) 102.400MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   896 start  960 end 1060 total 1224 skew    0 clock  83.66KHz
        v: height  672 start  672 end  674 total  697           clock  60.01Hz
  1024x576 (0x5d) 98.500MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width  1024 start 1092 end 1200 total 1376 skew    0 clock  71.58KHz
        v: height  576 start  577 end  580 total  597           clock  59.95Hz
  1024x576 (0x5e) 78.375MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1064 total 1104 skew    0 clock  70.99KHz
        v: height  576 start  577 end  580 total  592           clock  59.96Hz
  1024x576 (0x5f) 46.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1064 end 1160 total 1296 skew    0 clock  35.88KHz
        v: height  576 start  579 end  584 total  599           clock  59.90Hz
  1024x576 (0x60) 42.000MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1072 end 1104 total 1184 skew    0 clock  35.47KHz
        v: height  576 start  579 end  584 total  593           clock  59.82Hz
  960x600 (0x61) 96.625MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   960 start 1028 end 1128 total 1296 skew    0 clock  74.56KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  604 total  622           clock  59.93Hz
  960x600 (0x62) 77.000MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   960 start  984 end 1000 total 1040 skew    0 clock  74.04KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  604 total  617           clock  60.00Hz
  960x540 (0x63) 86.500MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   960 start 1024 end 1124 total 1288 skew    0 clock  67.16KHz
        v: height  540 start  541 end  544 total  560           clock  59.96Hz
  960x540 (0x64) 69.250MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   960 start  984 end 1000 total 1040 skew    0 clock  66.59KHz
        v: height  540 start  541 end  544 total  555           clock  59.99Hz
  960x540 (0x65) 40.750MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   960 start  992 end 1088 total 1216 skew    0 clock  33.51KHz
        v: height  540 start  543 end  548 total  562           clock  59.63Hz
  960x540 (0x66) 37.250MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width   960 start 1008 end 1040 total 1120 skew    0 clock  33.26KHz
        v: heigTht  540 start  543 end  548 total  556           clock  59.82Hz
  800x600 (0x67) 81.000MHz +HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   800 start  832 end  928 total 1080 skew    0 clock  75.00KHz
        v: height  600 start  600 end  602 total  625           clock  60.00Hz
  800x600 (0x68) 40.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock  37.88KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock  60.32Hz
  800x600 (0x69) 36.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  824 end  896 total 1024 skew    0 clock  35.16KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  603 total  625           clock  56.25Hz
  840x525 (0x6a) 73.125MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   840 start  892 end  980 total 1120 skew    0 clock  65.29KHz
        v: height  525 start  526 end  529 total  544           clock  60.01Hz
  840x525 (0x6b) 59.500MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   840 start  864 end  880 total  920 skew    0 clock  64.67KHz
        v: height  525 start  526 end  529 total  540           clock  59.88Hz
  864x486 (0x6c) 32.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   864 start  888 end  968 total 1072 skew    0 clock  30.32KHz
        v: height  486 start  489 end  494 total  506           clock  59.92Hz
  864x486 (0x6d) 30.500MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width   864 start  912 end  944 total 1024 skew    0 clock  29.79KHz
        v: height  486 start  489 end  494 total  500           clock  59.57Hz
  700x525 (0x6e) 61.000MHz +HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   700 start  744 end  820 total  940 skew    0 clock  64.89KHz
        v: height  525 start  526 end  532 total  541           clock  59.98Hz
  800x450 (0x6f) 59.125MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   800 start  848 end  928 total 1056 skew    0 clock  55.99KHz
        v: height  450 start  451 end  454 total  467           clock  59.95Hz
  800x450 (0x70) 48.750MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   800 start  824 end  840 total  880 skew    0 clock  55.40KHz
        v: height  450 start  451 end  454 total  463           clock  59.82Hz
  640x512 (0x71) 54.000MHz +HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   640 start  664 end  720 total  844 skew    0 clock  63.98KHz
        v: height  512 start  512 end  514 total  533           clock  60.02Hz
  700x450 (0x72) 51.750MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   700 start  740 end  812 total  924 skew    0 clock  56.01KHz
        v: height  450 start  451 end  456 total  467           clock  59.96Hz
  700x450 (0x73) 43.250MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   700 start  724 end  740 total  780 skew    0 clock  55.45KHz
        v: height  450 start  451 end  456 total  463           clock  59.88Hz
  640x480 (0x74) 54.000MHz +HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   640 start  688 end  744 total  900 skew    0 clock  60.00KHz
        v: height  480 start  480 end  482 total  500           clock  60.00Hz
  640x480 (0x75) 25.175MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  59.94Hz
  720x405 (0x76) 22.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   720 start  744 end  808 total  896 skew    0 clock  25.11KHz
        v: height  405 start  408 end  413 total  422           clock  59.51Hz
  720x405 (0x77) 21.750MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width   720 start  768 end  800 total  880 skew    0 clock  24.72KHz
        v: height  405 start  408 end  413 total  419           clock  58.99Hz
  684x384 (0x78) 42.625MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   684 start  720 end  788 total  892 skew    0 clock  47.79KHz
        v: height  384 start  385 end  390 total  399           clock  59.88Hz
  684x384 (0x79) 36.125MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   684 start  708 end  724 total  764 skew    0 clock  47.28KHz
        v: height  384 start  385 end  390 total  395           clock  59.85Hz
  640x400 (0x7a) 41.750MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   640 start  676 end  740 total  840 skew    0 clock  49.70KHz
        v: height  400 start  401 end  404 total  415           clock  59.88Hz
  640x400 (0x7b) 35.500MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   640 start  664 end  680 total  720 skew    0 clock  49.31KHz
        v: height  400 start  401 end  404 total  411           clock  59.98Hz
  640x360 (0x7c) 37.250MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   640 start  672 end  736 total  832 skew    0 clock  44.77KHz
        v: height  360 start  361 end  364 total  374           clock  59.86Hz
  640x360 (0x7d) 31.875MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   640 start  664 end  680 total  720 skew    0 clock  44.27KHz
        v: height  360 start  361 end  364 total  370           clock  59.83Hz
  640x360 (0x7e) 18.000MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   640 start  664 end  720 total  800 skew    0 clock  22.50KHz
        v: height  360 start  363 end  368 total  376           clock  59.84Hz
  640x360 (0x7f) 17.750MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  688 end  720 total  800 skew    0 clock  22.19KHz
        v: height  360 start  363 end  368 total  374           clock  59.32Hz
  512x384 (0x80) 32.500MHz -HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   512 start  524 end  592 total  672 skew    0 clock  48.36KHz
        v: height  384 start  385 end  388 total  403           clock  60.00Hz
  512x288 (0x81) 23.250MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   512 start  532 end  580 total  648 skew    0 clock  35.88KHz
        v: height  288 start  289 end  292 total  299           clock  60.00Hz
  512x288 (0x82) 21.000MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   512 start  536 end  552 total  592 skew    0 clock  35.47KHz
        v: height  288 start  289 end  292 total  296           clock  59.92Hz
  480x270 (0x83) 20.375MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   480 start  496 end  544 total  608 skew    0 clock  33.51KHz
        v: height  270 start  271 end  274 total  281           clock  59.63Hz
  480x270 (0x84) 18.625MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   480 start  504 end  520 total  560 skew    0 clock  33.26KHz
        v: height  270 start  271 end  274 total  278           clock  59.82Hz
  400x300 (0x85) 20.000MHz +HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   400 start  420 end  484 total  528 skew    0 clock  37.88KHz
        v: height  300 start  300 end  302 total  314           clock  60.32Hz
  400x300 (0x86) 18.000MHz +HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   400 start  412 end  448 total  512 skew    0 clock  35.16KHz
        v: height  300 start  300 end  301 total  312           clock  56.34Hz
  432x243 (0x87) 16.250MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   432 start  444 end  484 total  536 skew    0 clock  30.32KHz
        v: height  243 start  244 end  247 total  253           clock  59.92Hz
  432x243 (0x88) 15.250MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   432 start  456 end  472 total  512 skew    0 clock  29.79KHz
        v: height  243 start  244 end  247 total  250           clock  59.57Hz
  320x240 (0x89) 12.587MHz -HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   320 start  328 end  376 total  400 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  240 start  245 end  246 total  262           clock  60.05Hz
  360x202 (0x8a) 11.250MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   360 start  372 end  404 total  448 skew    0 clock  25.11KHz
        v: height  202 start  204 end  206 total  211           clock  59.51Hz
  360x202 (0x8b) 10.875MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   360 start  384 end  400 total  440 skew    0 clock  24.72KHz
        v: height  202 start  204 end  206 total  209           clock  59.13Hz
  320x180 (0x8c)  9.000MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   320 start  332 end  360 total  400 skew    0 clock  22.50KHz
        v: height  180 start  181 end  184 total  188           clock  59.84Hz
  320x180 (0x8d)  8.875MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   320 start  344 end  360 total  400 skew    0 clock  22.19KHz
        v: height  180 start  181 end  184 total  187           clock  59.32Hz
```

(The external monitor is DP-1-1.)

As I suspected the graphics driver to be the problem, I used `mhwd` to switch from "video-linux" (which is basically nouveau) to the proprietary driver "video-hybrid-intel-nvidia-390xx-bumblebee".

However, using this driver, the external monitor (along with several other outputs) was no longer shown. The output of `xrandr`:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1600 x 900, maximum 32767 x 32767
LVDS1 connected primary 1600x900+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 310mm x 170mm
   1600x900      60.06*+  40.32  
   1400x900      59.88  
   1368x768      60.00    59.88    59.85  
   1280x800      59.81    59.91  
   1280x720      59.86    60.00    59.74  
   1024x768      60.00  
   1024x576      60.00    59.90    59.82  
   960x540       60.00    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   864x486       60.00    59.92    59.57  
   800x450       60.00  
   640x480       59.94  
   720x405       59.51    60.00    58.99  
   640x360       59.84    59.32    60.00  
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Using another driver (video-nvidia-390xx), the external monitor worked fine, but the laptop's own monitor (which was LVDS-1/LVDS1 in the previous `xrandr` outputs) was no longer shown:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 4608 x 1440, maximum 16384 x 16384
VGA-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
LVDS-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 connected primary 2560x1440+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 526mm x 296mm panning 4608x1440+0+0
   2560x1440     59.95*+
   2048x1080     60.00    24.00  
   1920x1200     59.88  
   1920x1080     60.00    59.94    50.00    23.98  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x720      59.94    50.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    59.94    59.93  
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

(The external monitor is DP-2)

This confirmed my assumption that I was dealing with a diver-issue but didn't solve my problem (as I need to use the monitor of the laptop for obvious reasons).

Furthermore, [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bumblebee#Output_wired_to_the_NVIDIA_chip) solution using `intel-virtual-output` (w/ the "video-hybrid-intel-nvidia-390xx-bumblebee" driver) didn't work either.

Another solution I tried was using `bbswitch` (w/ the "video-hybrid-intel-nvidia-390xx-bumblebee" driver) to turn the discrete graphics card on and then running `sudo systemctl restart display-manager` but the external monitor still didn't show up in `xrandr`.

How can I get both monitors (external and laptop monitor) to work at the same time?
Why is the monitor recognized using the "video-linux" driver but I can't get it to receive any input?
Why does the monitor work with the proprietary "video-nvidia-390xx" driver but not with the (also proprietary) "video-hybrid-intel-nvidia-390xx-bumblebee" driver?

[The output of `inxi -Fxxxz` with the "video-linux" driver](https://pastebin.com/hAyEM86F)
[`inxi -G` w/ "video-hybrid-intel-nvidia-390xx-bumblebee"](https://pastebin.com/2GY7km1H)
[`inxi -G` w/ "video-nvidia-390xx"](https://pastebin.com/bvTMDX13)

Comment: _GreenSmurf_, it's OK to post a link to mountains of text, say at Google Drive, when it overwhelms what can easily be read in a question. Excellent detail, though!

Comment: @K7AAY I moved the output of the `inxi` commands to pastebin, thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried [this solution](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bumblebee#Output_wired_to_the_NVIDIA_chip) again. However, I changed `/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia` before running `optirun intel-virtual-output`  and it worked this time. The Archwiki didn't mention that this must be done beforehand so I had only changed the configuration files afterwards and re-running `optirun intel-virtual-output` probably didn't work as there was already an instance of it running.